# How to use 'sed or gawk' to delete a text block until the third line previous the last one

Tags: sed, gawk

Good day,
I was wondering how to delete a text block like this:

```
1    
2    
3    
4    
5    
6    
7    
8
```

and delete from the second line until the third line previous the last one, to obtain:

```
1    
2    
6    
7    
8
```

Thanks in advance!!!

**BTW** This text block is just an example, the real text blocks I working on are huge and each one differs among them in the line numbers.

Comment: You don't need sed for this: `awk 'NR<=2 {print} {for(i=3;i>=2;--i) x[i]=x[i-1]; x[1] = $0;} END {for(i=3;i>=1;--i) print x[i]}'`

Comment: It looks good... but...instead of numbers, how can i use it with text lines?

Comment: It works with all types of lines: `$0` is the entire line

Comment: rolled back the Question EDIT to OP's original. @Nirk why you removed all awk stuff from the question, after OP added them?

Comment: @kent when I looked at the history it looked like someone else added awk, but on closer inspection I see it was the OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the number of lines with `wc` and using `awk` to print the requested range:

```
$ awk 'NR<M || NR>N-M' M=3 N="$(wc -l file)" file
1
2
6
7
8
```

This allows you to easily change the range by just changing the value of `M`.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '3,${:a;$!{N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;D}}' file
```

or i f you prefer:

```
sed '1,2b;:a;$!{N;s/\n/&/3;Ta;D}' file
```

These always print the first two lines, then build a running window of three lines.
Unless the end of file is reached the first line is popped off the window and deleted. At the end of file the remaining 3 lines are printed.

Answer (score 2):

since you mentioned **huge** and also line numbers could be **differ**. I would suggest this awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR<3{print;next}{delete a[NR-3];a[NR]=$0}END{for(x=NR-2;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}' file
```

- it processes the input file only once, without (pre) calculating total line numbers
- it stores minimal data in memory,  in all processing time, only 3 lines data were stored.
- If you want to change the filtering criteria, for example, removing from line `x` to `$-y`, you just simply change the offset in the oneliner.

add a test:

```
kent$  seq 8|awk 'NR<3{print;next}{delete a[NR-3];a[NR]=$0}END{for(x=NR-2;x<=NR;x++)print a[x]}'
1
2
6
7
8
```

Comment: @DavidAlejandro if performance is not an issue, using `wc -l` to calculate the line number would be easier. This solution keeps only 3 lines in buffer, and print them out at the end.

Comment: To the downvoter : would u pls add some explanation, why the answer is so bad? I am glad to learn.

Comment: @kent seconded, I guess somebody doesn't like awk?

Comment: @sudo_O it is really strange. if you check the edit history of the question, OP had edited it, to add `gawk` tag, and also the title, added the "awk" part. moreover he had accepted awk solution as answer. but the guy Nirk came and edit the question again, just removed all "awk" stuff.... I rolledback the edit to OP's.

Comment: Hmmm and if you look at his profile he down votes more than he upvotes!

Comment: @sudo_O I don't even know there is a report like that... good to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -n '
    ## Append second line, print first two lines and delete them.
    N; 
    p; 
    s/^.*$//;
    ## Read next three lines removing leading newline character inserted
    ## by the "N" command.
    N; 
    s/^\n//; 
    N; 
    :a; 
    N;
    ## I will keep three lines in buffer until last line when I will print
    ## them and exit.
    $ { p; q };
    ## Not last line yet, so remove one line of buffer based in FIFO algorithm.
    s/^[^\n]*\n//; 
    ## Goto label "a".
    ba
' infile
```

It yields:

```
1
2
6
7
8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is quiet messy